# connection.getType() is returning null in ios

Tags: gwt, cordova, mgwt

I am using gwt-Phonegap version 1.7.0. 
I have build the application and it is working fine on android device. 
But the same application when i deployed in ios using Xcode, the method phonegap.getconnection() is returning null value.

is there any settings I need to set in xcode to get connection information?

Please help me in this regard.
Thanks and Regards,
Ganesh

Comment: can you post your actual code, this is most likely an initialisation error

Comment: HI Daniel, Thank you for the reply please find code here under :     
PhoneGap phoneGap = GWT.create(PhoneGap.class);
phoneGap.initializePhoneGap();
// This method is returning the actual connection type on android device but for ios its returning null
String connType = phoneGap.getConnection().getType();
//this method is returning ethernet as connection type on simulator
Connection connMode = new ConnectionBrowserImpl();
// This method is returning the acutal connection type on android device but for ios its returning null
// Connection connMode = new ConnectionBrowserImpl();

Comment: Hi Daniel due to limitation on number of characters i have posted in unformated code sorry for that....

Answer (score 0):

For gwt phonegap to work properly you need to initialize it like this:

```
final PhoneGap phoneGap = GWT.create(PhoneGap.class);

phoneGap.addHandler(new PhoneGapAvailableHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onPhoneGapAvailable(PhoneGapAvailableEvent event) {
                //start your app - phonegap is ready

        }
});

phoneGap.addHandler(new PhoneGapTimeoutHandler() {

        @Override
        public void onPhoneGapTimeout(PhoneGapTimeoutEvent event) {
                //can not start phonegap - something is for with your setup

        }
});
```

Otherwise you will not be able to use phonegap. (this is basically the same boot mechanism that runs in native javascript if you use phonegap directly)

Comment: Thanks a lot Daniel that really worked but to my surprise even this code is working fine PhoneGap phoneGap = GWT.create(PhoneGap.class); String conn = phoneGap.getConnection().getType(); Actually problem in my sys is that previously there is phonegap 2.0 which I have downgraded to 1.7.0 but could not complete unistallation of 2.0 version and xcode is taking javascript file of 2.0 which is breaking and even I have ignored. I have completely removed 2.0 version created a new project and now its working fine. Thank you once again for the support.